# Group by data on multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have done the below which shows me the data I need.

But it displays the data on multiple rows. I would like it all condensing on the same row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFoSJ.png)

```
select t.fqn,
case when t.stat = 'ACTIVE' then t.stat_count end as Active,
case when t.stat = 'RELEASED' then t.stat_count end as Released,
case when t.stat = 'ALLOCATED' then t.stat_count end as Allocated,
case when t.stat = 'ALLOCATING' then t.stat_count end as Allocating,
case when t.stat = 'PASSIVE' then t.stat_count end as Passive
from
(
select l.fullyqualifiedname as fqn, pg.controllerstatus as stat ,  count (pg.id) as stat_count
from   task pg
left join packgroup pgt
on pgt.id = pg.id
left join location l
on l.id = pg.EXECUTIONLOCATIONID
left join location l2
on l2.id = pg.locationid
where  pg.TASKTYPEKEY = task_def.TASKTYPE_PACKGROUP
and pg.controllerstatus ! = 'EXECUTED'
group by    l.fullyqualifiedname    , pg.controllerstatus   )  t
```

Comment: Please put the data in your image as ascii text. Also, update your Question with the Oracle tag, so it's searchable. You should give example of data in the tables of your query. Include your desired result as well, so everyone knows what you mean by "all condensing on the same row" Kindly see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). There's a tool there to make is easier to make ascii tables.

Comment: May I ask: Why did you chose to not update your Question to make it valid on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

It works using this code:

```sql
select *
    from (
    select
    SUBSTR(l.fullyqualifiedname,5,10) as fqn,
    p.planningstatus,
    packgroupTask.controllerstatus as controllerstatus
    from
        Task packgroupTask
           left join PackGroup packgroup on packgroup.id = packgroupTask.id
           left join location l on l.id = packgroupTask.executionLocationId
           left join location l2 on l2.id = packgroupTask.locationId
           full join palletizeroverview p on SUBSTR(p.moduleid,-6,10) = SUBSTR(l.fullyqualifiedname,8,10)
        where
           packgroupTask.taskTypeKey = TASK_DEF.TASKTYPE_PACKGROUP
           and packgroupTask.controllerstatus ! = 'EXECUTED')
    pivot (count(controllerstatus)
         for controllerstatus
          in ('ACTIVE' ACTIVE,
              'RELEASED' RELEASED,
              'ALLOCATED' ALLOCATED,
              'ALLOCATING' ALLOCATING,
              'PASSSIVE' PASSIVE))
order by fqn
```

Comment: Thumbs up for solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if this syntax is correct, I don't have a right place to test it. So it is just an idea, use Pivot.

```sql
select 
   l.fullyqualifiedname as fqn,
   pg.controllerstatus as stat,
   pg.id as pg_id
from
   task pg left join packgroup pgt on pgt.id = pg.id
   left join location l on l.id = pg.EXECUTIONLOCATIONID
   left join location l2 on l2.id = pg.locationid
where
   pg.TASKTYPEKEY = task_def.TASKTYPE_PACKGROUP
   and pg.controllerstatus ! = 'EXECUTED'
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(pg_id) 
    FOR g.controllerstatus
    IN (  'ACTIVE', 'RELEASED', 'ALLOCATED', 'ALLOCATING', 'PASSIVE' )
)
```

The exact technical information for pivot is there https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-pivot/